Global existence of solution to ODE
I would like to show global existence of solution of following system of ODEs:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = c + y^2 z - (d+1)y\\
\frac{dz}{dx} = d y - y^2 z,\\ 
\end{equation}
where $c,d>0$ are parameters and $y,z\geq0 $. I managed to show that the solution always stays non-negative in both $y,z$. I tried to prove boundedness of the solution (which implies global existence) using the following function $V(y,z) = y + z$, whose derivative is $\frac{dV}{dx} = c - y$. This implies boundedness of $y$ ($y$ is non-negative). But how to show that $z$ is also bounded? Maybe a totally different approach will be better.
Thank you for any help.

Hello -you are almost there. Since $\frac{d}{dt}(y+z) \le c$, you know that $y(t) + z(t) \le y(0) + z(0) + ct$ for all $t$. Since $y, z \ge 0$, both $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ must satisfy the same bound.
